# Ping operation working perfectly in pycharm but not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, ping, prettytable

I have a piece of code that will ping 2 servers with a specific IP addresses mentioned in the code and it will list the time taken for the pings in the form of a prettytable. When i execute the same code in pycharm it is working fine .However if i execute it in jupyter notebook, the code is not getting executed and as a result the time of the pings is not updated in the pretty table.Can any body tell me what  the issue is?

This is the output i got in console:
Table For Ping Timings:
+------------------+---------------------+
| TIME FOR 8.8.8.8 | TIME FOR 13.32.32.0 |
+------------------+---------------------+
|        32        |         236         |
|        19        |         234         |
|        46        |         227         |
|        45        |         241         |
|        29        |         239         |
|        33        |         234         |
|        21        |         230         |
|        22        |         226         |
|        26        |         235         |
|        26        |         235         |
|        24        |         238         |
|        20        |         243         |
|        26        |         234         |
|        26        |         233         |
|        26        |         238         |
|        27        |         232         |
|       123        |         240         |
|        29        |         233         |
|        39        |         241         |
|        29        |         453         |
|        26        |         234         |
|        43        |         236         |
|        30        |         255         |
|        20        |         233         |
|        35        |         238         |
|        21        |         245         |
|        36        |         232         |
|        47        |         262         |
|        23        |         242         |
|        28        |         243         |
|        25        |         246         |
|        24        |         232         |
|        34        |         235         |
|        55        |         237         |
|        37        |         227         |
|        36        |         240         |
|        21        |         255         |
|        27        |         227         |
|        33        |         235         |
|        38        |         235         |
|        25        |         251         |
|        28        |         249         |
|        19        |         234         |
|        27        |         233         |
|        27        |         237         |
|        40        |         244         |
|        24        |         232         |
|        20        |         229         |
|        27        |         235         |
|        32        |         230         |
+------------------+---------------------+

```
import subprocess
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from prettytable import PrettyTable
def req():
print("pinging 8.8.8.X....")
print()
h = 0

try:
    Q = [line.rpartition('_')[-1] for line in subprocess.check_output("ping -n 50 8.8.8.8").splitlines()[2:-4]]
except:
    Q = "Request timed out."

i = 0
j = 0
g = 0
k = 0
w = 0
k = 0
x = []
while i < 50:
    if Q != "Request timed out.":
        while w < 50:
            comp = re.search(r'time=\d{1,4}', Q[i])
            if hasattr(comp, 'group'):
                T = comp.group(0)[5:9]
                x.append(T)
                w = w + 1
                i = i + 1
            else:
                T = 0
                x.append(T)
                w = w + 1
                i = i + 1
                k = k + 1
                if k == 5:
                    plt.plot(x, marker='o')
                    break
        plt.plot(x, marker='o')
    else:
        T = 0
        x.append(T)
        i = i + 1
        g = g + 1
        if g == 5:
            plt.plot(x, marker='o')
            s = 1
            while s < 46:
                x.append('-')
                s = s + 1
                i = i + 1
                g = g + 1

print("pings for 8.8.8.X are done")
print()
print("pinging 13.32.32.0")

try:
    A = [line.rpartition('_')[-1] for line in subprocess.check_output("ping -n 50 13.32.32.0").splitlines()[2:-4]]
except:
    A = "Request timed out."
n = 0
d = 0
e = 0
l = 0
y = []
while n < 50:
    if A != "Request timed out.":
        while d < 50:
            comp = re.search(r'time=\d{1,4}', A[n])
            if hasattr(comp, 'group'):
                B = comp.group(0)[5:9]
                y.append(B)
                n = n + 1
                d = d + 1
            else:
                B = 0
                y.append(B)
                n = n + 1
                d = d + 1
                l = l + 1
                if l == 5:
                    plt.plot(y, marker='o')
                    break
        plt.plot(y, marker='o')
    else:
        B = 0
        y.append(B)
        n = n + 1
        e = e + 1
        if e == 5:
            plt.plot(y, marker='o')
            t = 1
            while t < 46:
                y.append('-')
                t = t + 1
                n = n + 1
                e = e + 1

print()
print("pings for 13.32.32.0 are done")
print()
print("Table For Ping Timings:")
u = 0
table = PrettyTable(["TIME FOR 8.8.8.8", "TIME FOR 13.32.32.0"])
while u < 50:
    table.add_row([x[u], y[u]])
    u = u + 1
print(table)

plt.ylabel("TIME IN ms")
plt.xlabel("NUMBER OF PINGS")
plt.title("GRAPH to Display Latency")
plt.margins(0.025)
plt.legend(['ping for 8.8.8.8', 'ping for 13.32.32.0'], loc='upper left')
if len(sys.argv) == 2:

    try:
        j = sys.argv[1].split('.')
        if j[1] == ".gif":
            print()
            print("FILE NOT SAVED: INCORRECT FILE FORMAT:FORMAT SHOULD BE (name.png/name.jpg)")
            plt.show()
        else:
            plt.savefig(sys.argv[1])
            plt.show()
    except:
        print()
        print("ERROR:FILE IS NOT SAVED:EXTENSION IS REQUIRED(.png/.jpg)")
        plt.show()
else:
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   req()
```

[This is the output i am getting in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dCLC.jpg)

This is the output:
Table For Ping Timings:
+------------------+---------------------+
| TIME FOR 8.8.8.8 | TIME FOR 13.32.32.0 |
+------------------+---------------------+
|        32        |         236         |
|        19        |         234         |
|        46        |         227         |
|        45        |         241         |
|        29        |         239         |
|        33        |         234         |
|        21        |         230         |
|        22        |         226         |
|        26        |         235         |
|        26        |         235         |
|        24        |         238         |
|        20        |         243         |
|        26        |         234         |
|        26        |         233         |
|        26        |         238         |
|        27        |         232         |
|       123        |         240         |
|        29        |         233         |
|        39        |         241         |
|        29        |         453         |
|        26        |         234         |
|        43        |         236         |
|        30        |         255         |
|        20        |         233         |
|        35        |         238         |
|        21        |         245         |
|        36        |         232         |
|        47        |         262         |
|        23        |         242         |
|        28        |         243         |
|        25        |         246         |
|        24        |         232         |
|        34        |         235         |
|        55        |         237         |
|        37        |         227         |
|        36        |         240         |
|        21        |         255         |
|        27        |         227         |
|        33        |         235         |
|        38        |         235         |
|        25        |         251         |
|        28        |         249         |
|        19        |         234         |
|        27        |         233         |
|        27        |         237         |
|        40        |         244         |
|        24        |         232         |
|        20        |         229         |
|        27        |         235         |
|        32        |         230         |
+------------------+---------------------+

Comment: please add output in text format.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the output in text format.